# Persistent connection of laravel queue workers?

Tags: database, laravel, queue, laravel-5.4

When using database as queue driver for Laravel, does this mean that the queue workers are persistently connected to the database? Been trying to figure out the high database connections even when we only have few users in our site. Thanks for the help!